# How to order by string length in TypeORM?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

In raw sql you can order by string length by using `LENGTH` keyword like this: `ORDER BY LENGTH(column) DESC`.
I've tried to use it in typeorm query builder like this `.orderBy("LENGTH(u.name)", "ASC")` but it throws an error:

```
"LENGTH(u" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

Is it possible to do in TypeORM?

Comment: Can you post the full query? Thanks

Comment: I wrote a simplified query example for you and for some reason it worked. After some digging in the original query I noticed that `leftJoin` is causing the issue with orderBy.
This is the original simplified query that throws this error:
`exhRepo.createQueryBuilder("e").select(["e.id", "e.company", "e.tax_id"]).leftJoinAndSelect("e.legal_form", "l") .orderBy("LENGTH(e.company)", "ASC").take(5).getMany();`
It works fine when I remove `LENGTH` keyword.

Comment: Actually it's not the issue with `leftJoin`. The issue is with combination of `leftJoin` and `take`. When I use only one of them it works, but when I use both then it breaks.

Comment: I made an issue for that: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7822